# How to stop training CNN part while continue training ANN part in a Multi-input Model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I made a *multi-input* model in Keras which takes image `shape=[N, 640, 480, 3]` as well as numerical data `shape=[N, 19]` and does prediction on 12 classes.
Following is the model defining part of code:

```
# # %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
# #                       MODEL === CNN
# # %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
#
base_model = keras.applications.ResNet50(
    weights='imagenet',  # Load weights pre-trained on ImageNet.
    input_shape=(640, 480, 3),
    include_top=False)  # Do not include the ImageNet classifier at the top.

base_model.trainable = False
input_Cnn = keras.Input(shape=(640, 480, 3))

x = base_model(input_Cnn, training=False)
# Convert features of shape `base_model.output_shape[1:]` to vectors
x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
# A Dense classifier with a single unit (binary classification)
x1 = keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation="relu")(x)
out_Cnn = keras.layers.Dense(12, activation="relu")(x1)

# %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
#                       MODEL === NN
# %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
inp_num = keras.layers.Input(shape=(19,))  # no. of columns of the numerical data
fc1 = keras.layers.Dense(units=2 ** 6, activation="relu")(inp_num)
fc2 = keras.layers.Dense(units=2 ** 8, activation="relu")(fc1)
fc3 = keras.layers.Dense(units=2 ** 10, activation="relu")(fc2)
fc4 = keras.layers.Dense(units=2 ** 8, activation="relu")(fc3)
fc5 = keras.layers.Dense(units=2 ** 6, activation="relu")(fc4)
out_NN = keras.layers.Dense(12, activation="relu")(fc5)

# %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
#                       CONCATENATION
# %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
result = keras.layers.concatenate((out_Cnn, out_NN), axis=-1)  # [N, 12] --- concatenate [N, 12] ==> [N, 24]
result = keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(result)
result = keras.layers.Dense(units=12, activation="softmax")(result)

model = keras.Model([input_Cnn, inp_num], result)

print(model.summary())
```

Problem is that the CNN part (if independently trained) trains in a less number of epochs while the ANN part (if independently trained) takes a longer time (more epochs). But here in this code when both are combined, accuracy doesn't go beyond 10%. Is there any way to stop gradients flowing into the CNN part after a certain number of epochs so that after that model trains only the ANN part?

Answer (score 0):

Im not using keras but after a quick google search this should be the answer:
You can freeze layers, so that certain parameters are not learnable anymore:

```py
# this freezes the first N layers
for layer in model.layers[:N]:
    layer.trainable = False
```

Where `N` is the amount of convolutional layers you have.